# ffmpeg wma to wav

Tags: ffmpeg

I've tried all sorts of parameters with ffmpeg to make this work, but they all result in a staticy audio file as a result.

some of what i've tried are:

> ffmpeg -i file.wma file.wav
>   ffmpeg -sameq -i file.wma file.wav
>   ffmpeg -i file.wma -ar 44100 -ac 1 -ab 64000 file.wav
>   ffmpeg -i file.wma -vn 64000 file.wav

Here's a link to the audio file:
(Removed broken link)

Comment: Is the original wma file staticy? Have you played it with VLC or Windows Media?

Comment: The file was created in Windows using the sound recorder.  In VLC and Windows Media Player the wma sounds fine.

Comment: ffmpeg under Windows or Linux?

Comment: Linux, sorry for missing that detail

Comment: By the way, you probably know, but avoid WMA if you can, it's a horrible format. The best alternatives include AAC and OGG Vorbis.

Comment: I totally agree.  Windows Media Player by default uses it though.  You have to go through all kinds of shenanigans in order to output a wav using it though.

Comment: Question cannot be closed, because it has an open bounty??? But it should be absolutely clear, that this question does not belong here! It is wrong here! A bounty should not make this one sticky here? :(

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize I had to click the +50 to give the bounty.  Makes more sense that when you choose an answer, they receive the bounty as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is working with `ffmpeg -i Untitled.wma Untitled.wav` for me, using ffmpeg from the Ubuntu repositories.

Version output:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Sep 16 2011 17:04:18, gcc: 4.4.3
FFmpeg SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1.2
libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
```

Maybe it helps.

Comment: thanks for the version output and verification it works - i'm going to try and update some stuff and then try again

Answer (score 0):

Use Mplayer to convert wma to wav

```
mplayer -ao pcm:file-name-in-wav.wav file-name-in-wma.wma
```

or

Use FFMpeg

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.wma myfile.wav
```